# Vertex AI - Viewing Pipeline Output

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/schedule-cloud-scheduler) tutorial to create my first scheduled Vertex AI Pipeline to run every minute. The only thing it does is prints `"Hello, <any-greet-string>"` and also returns this same string. I can see that it is running because the last run time updates and the last run result is "Success" every time.

My question is very simple: Where can I see this string printed and the output of my pipeline?

Comment: Hi @Ivar Eriksson. If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `print()` statements in the pipeline can be found in "Cloud Logging" with the appropriate filters. To check logs for each component in the pipeline, click on the respective component in the console and click "**VIEW LOGS**" in the right pane. A new pane with the logs will open in the pipeline page which will allow us to see the output of the component. Refer to the below screenshot.

[image]

I ran a sample [pipeline](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro#4) from this codelab, [Intro to Vertex Pipelines](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro#0) and below is the output for one of the `print()` statements in the pipeline.

[image]

##### UPDATE:

Every component in a pipeline run is deployed as an individual Vertex AI custom job. Corresponding to the sample pipeline consisting 3 components, there are 3 entries in the "CUSTOM JOBS" section as shown below.

[image]

Therefore, to view the logs on the run level, we would need to query the log entries with the respective `job_id`s of the pipeline components and the `job_id` of the Cloud Scheduler job. The query would look like this.

```sql
resource.labels.job_id=("JOB_ID_1" OR "JOB_ID_2" [OR "JOB_ID_N"...])
severity>=DEFAULT
```

If there are no simultaneous pipeline runs, a simpler query like below can be used.

```sql
resource.type=("cloud_scheduler_job" OR "ml_job")
severity>=DEFAULT
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I see this on a run level as well for something on a schedule?

Comment: @IvarEriksson I have updated the answer for your other question.