# How do I get Vertex AI pipeline output?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

I define a Vertex AI pipeline thus:

```
@dsl.pipeline
def pipe_pipeline(arg1: str, arg2: str) -> str:
...
```

compile it:

```
compiler.Compiler().compile(pipe_pipeline, 'pipeline.yaml')
```

and submit it:

```
ml_pipeline_job = aiplatform.PipelineJob(
    display_name='pipeline.yaml',
    template_path='pipeline.yaml',
    pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT,
    parameter_values={"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2},
    enable_caching=False
)
```

but how do I retrieve the output `-> str:` in the pipeline definition?

Answer (score 0):

Per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379395/vertex-ai-viewing-pipeline-output) ''the output of the `print()` statements in the pipeline can be found in "Cloud Logging" with the appropriate filters. To check logs for each component in the pipeline, click on the respective component in the console and click "**VIEW LOGS**" in the right pane. A new pane with the logs will open in the pipeline page which will allow us to see the output of the component.''